# Breaking up a long unix command?

Tags: c#, unix, ssh

I'm sending a pretty long command via SSH from C# to a unix box and it seems the command is to long to run.  I read you can escape it via [enter] but I have some quotation shenanigans going on to where it keeps saying unmatched quotes.

Example Cmd:

`tibrvsend "Destination" "really really long string"`

Just flat out doesnt send

`tibrvsend "Destination" "really really\`

`long string"`

has unmatched " error.

I'm sure this is simple, can you guys help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a string concatenation operator in C#?

Comment: @larsmans The problem isnt the C# side, its getting the long string to run on the unix box... its actually more of a unix question I guess

Comment: You mean you get an error message from the other side? If so, please post it.

Comment: @larsmans Yes the unmatched " error is on the unix side: `Unmatched ".`

Comment: That doesn't mean the string is too long. It means you're quoting it in the wrong way.

Comment: @larsmans I figured it was because the break was in a quoted string, so something like "\"stuff "\\[enter] "more stuff\"" ?

Comment: That should work, I think, if each backslash is followed immediately by a newline character.

Comment: How long is ‛really really long string‛? 8 inches or less? Could it be that the string contains a "?

Comment: @ott-- Its 4402 characters, way past the unix command prompt limit

Comment: Check your files under /usr/include for ARG_MAX and _POSIX_ARG_MAX, I think you hit the latter value. Is it possible that you read the values from a file or a fifo instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SSH session is persistent, you can declare a shell script variable (e.g. `$myvar='string'`), then concatenate other part of that (long) string to the end of the string in multiple commands and then run the command by passing that variable to it instead of sending it the whole string.

Comment: So I think the problem is that the cap on one unix command on the prompt is like 500 char, would this get around this?

Comment: It depends on the type of shell you are connecting via, but by this method you can be sure that it will work. Also you can make a variable to determine the splitting size of the string to make sure it work in cases of remote environment changes.

Comment: And remember that you have to keep your shell session alive for the whole period.